# While searching questions by tags, why cannot we choose more than one tag only?

Tags: support, tags, search

While searching questions by tags, why cannot we choose more than one tag only?

Let us say someone wants to narrow the number of proposed questions, for example, from 100 to just 4-5 questions he or she is interested in, so is this possible on the site? Let us say someone is interested in tag [astrophysics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astrophysics) and can view how many questions are asked and then he or she can choose another tag let us say tag [visible-light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visible-light) always with the information of how many questions are present for that tag and all remaining tags.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Multiple tag searches are possible. E.g. the search for both [astrophysics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astrophysics) & [visible-light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visible-light) is done [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astrophysics+visible-light).

Unfortunately tags are not always applied consistently, so for a more complete search type [keywords](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+astrophysics+light) rather than tags, or use [Google](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=astrophysics+light&as_sitesearch=https%3A%2F%2Fphysics.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F).

By the way, when you search, there often appears an 'Advanced Search Tips' button. Be sure to check that out.

Answer (score 4):

First, make sure that those tags are defined before. Now, for example, in the search engine, type this:

**[general-relativity] [black-holes]**

And you will [see this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-relativity%2Bblack-holes?tab=Active):

[image]

Comment: I think like so...when you start typing letters in the search box the list of tags is updated so when you find the right you click on it and after the page is refreshed this tag appears above the list of all other tags...now you start typing the letters for the second tag and the list is again updated as you type  in..but all that tags should have a subscript meaning the number of available questions for that tag.....